Integrate and Run Cucumber Based Integration Tests from Zephyr
I have a repository of cucumber tests written with Maven. I want to expose these to the zephyr so that when I execute the test case, it can directly run the suite of integration tests. I'm going to pass a set of tags to the integration test suite.
I see there are cucumber BDD integration available but they only allow you to write Gherkin files and you need to manually export them to the test repository and run them, and then come back to Zephyr to upload the results.
I'm looking to automate this process
